# Issue in Importing Magento Database

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to import magento database that i previously exported and saved in my system but now when i'm trying to import it gives following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that...
>   I have tried importing it with command line but that also did'nt solve
>   my issue and. Please help to sort out my issue.

```
 CREATE TABLE `cmg_admin_assert` (   `assert_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT
 NULL COMMENT 'Assert ID',   `assert_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
 COMMENT AS `Assert Type`,   `assert_data` text COMMENT 'Assert Data' )
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Admin Assert Table';
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below query:

```
CREATE TABLE `cmg_admin_assert` (
  `assert_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Assert ID',
  `assert_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Assert Type',
  `assert_data` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Assert Data'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Admin Assert Table';
```

Instead of

```
CREATE TABLE `cmg_admin_assert` (   `assert_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT
 NULL COMMENT 'Assert ID',   `assert_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL
 COMMENT AS `Assert Type`,   `assert_data` text COMMENT 'Assert Data' )
 ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Admin Assert Table';
```

Comment: Thanks Sukumar, but other tables also have syntax errors but when i exported it and saved on my system it was working. Is mysql version is causing this issue?